# Using Javascript in Wicket

Tags: java, javascript, wicket

I find it confusing to incorporate javascript from Wicket using target.appendJavaScript()

What is the structure for doing this:

```
document.write("Celsius is: " + celsius + "");
```

in `target.appendJavaScript()`  ?

Lets say celsius is an integer from Java.. how do I include the java variable into the javascript code?

Comment: @Doge Keep in mind that Wicket uses Java and the OP is asking how to write Java code to append JavaScript to the DOM using Wicket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work.

```
int celsius = 0;
target.appendJavaScript("document.write(\"Celsius is: " + celsius + "\")");
```